# Which Exceptions get thrown from watson-developer-cloud pip module

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I started to migrate my Django apps to use the watson-developer-cloud module, and whilst running my unit tests noted that the service threw an exception under certain conditions. The exception turned out to be a WatsonException, which I now code for, but was wondering if that is the only exception that would be thrown. Currently my code looks like:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import LanguageTranslationV2 as LanguageTranslation
from watson_developer_cloud import WatsonException 
...
try:
  language_translation = LanguageTranslation(username='xxxx',
                                             password='yyy')

  languages_detected =  language_translation.identify(data)                                                ...   

except WatsonException as err:
  ...
```

My question is, is this sufficient to cover all error conditions?

Comment: What is your intention in covering all error conditions? What if the library has a bug that causes it to throw a different error - how do you want to handle that? Why not simply catch `Exception`?

Comment: I agree I can add a catch all, but there are certain actions that the application can take when the exception is known. For example if the service is down, then that can either be reported back or the function greyed out as not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently two exceptions:

```
class WatsonException(Exception):
    """Generic exception class."""
    pass
```

and

```
class WatsonInvalidArgument(Exception):
    """A parameter to a function or methods was invalid"""
    pass
```

- `WatsonInvalidArgument`: is only thrown when you are trying to call the API with invalid parameters; therefore, before doing the API call.
- `WatsonException`: is usually generated from a HTTP 401, 403, 500, 503, etc... Errors that are coming from the service or the underlying connection.